# water drained from one kitchen sink gushes out over another

Tags: drain, garbage-disposal, kitchen-sink

I have a two-sink combo in the kitchen and it looks like this (sorry for the somewhat gross appearance :-):

[image]

sometime when i wash dishes by hands, the food residues slow down the water flowing down the drain and as a result a pool is created on the left. Somehow, some water seems to find another way out to the sink on the right and emerge there.

It's not bad so far,'cause eventually the water went away down the drain. However before it did, if I decide to expedite the flow and turn on the garbage disposal which was installed underneath the left sink, water gushes out on the right like a fountain of dirty water, ruining everything in the vicinity.

The [garbage disposal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004U9JO) looks like the picture below, the vertical white pipe is connected to the sink on the right:

[image]

The disposal was also connected via a pipe to the dish washer on the left. When I used dish washer, some water also emerged on the left sink.

I bought the disposal (badger 5, I believe) and installed it myself 'cause the propeller of the old one stopped working. I thought I followed the instructions preciously and did a good job and it did seem to work. Now my wife suspected that I didn't install it the right way, I protested the idea as if it were my political legacy, somehow I can't rule out that possibility.

Anyway I am wondering if anyone can help me out explaining what might have gone wrong, as the whole thing doesn't seem normal.

Comment: We are dealing with the same thing. I read to get a small plunger and cover one side of your sink's drain while plunging the other side. Then switch and do the opposite - all while there is some standing water or you can run a little water. I quickly tried it and it's a little better, but I want to try it again with a better plunger. Good luck!

Comment: @deebs thanks, i am not sure if a plunger would work though, guess it never hurt to give it a try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I brought in a plumber today and it turned out that it's not the disposal but the pipe  got clogged. He used a drain cleaner to clean the pipe so no more standing water thus no water coming out from another hole.

Comment: Be sure to select your answer as the correct one to prevent this post returning for review later.